# How to cancel a processing order

Tags: sales-order, creditmemo

I will appreciate any advices.
I had a processing order (buyer bought via ebay) and was marked complete as the item has been sent. Buyer then open ebay dispute and we have refunded them.

After refund, my Magento automatically marked the invoice/sale record as processing again and im not able to cancel or issue credit memo on it.
On the invoice page, it is only showing the following tabs
back, edit, send email, hold, reorder.

Can anyone please advise me what should i do to cancel this order.

Answer (score 1):

Magento orders can be canceled ***until all items have been invoice***, e.g. `during the pending or processing state`. This automatically cancels payment and order items (which just set canceled tax amounts on the item). ***Invoices can be cancelled, returning order totals to pre-invoice state. Same goes for credit memos. Only shipments cannot be cancelled.***

In most cases when o*perations are cancelled, tax amounts are returned to the way they were before the operation (just like other price data). In case of an order, all the cancelled amounts are set to total invoices (whatever has not been invoiced yet is cancelled).*

Invoices and credit memos cannot be canceled from the interface, even though the functionality was implemented.